# SVG --> After saving my Illustrator project to svg format, it looks differently

Tags: svg, adobe-illustrator

Why does after saving my Illustrator project to svg format it looks differently than in project? Those are my 1. project and 2. svg file after save

project : https://postimg.org/image/93f0srcx9/

svg file after save: https://postimg.org/image/cn0yili7x/

This is the link to the illustrator file : https://files.fm/u/4paevkju

Comment: It's hard to say from just the pictures. Ultimately, the answer is probably going to be a bug in the Illustrator SVG exporter.  Especially if the SVG looks the same in all browsers.  Or perhaps you are using a blend mode that SVG doesn't support (or not yet). If you create a minimal sample (eg just the object that fails) we could tell you more.

Comment: What happens if you try saving the file as an older version of Illustrator?